How should I handle repeat questions in the Staging Ground?
On the main site, when someone repeatedly posts the same question, the new attempt can be closed as a duplicate of the old attempt, even if the first question was closed for a different reason and didn't receive any answers.
However, I have now seen at least one case where a question in the Staging Ground was marked as needing major changes (and had re-evaluation declined at least once), and then the OP decided to repost the question in the Staging Ground again rather than try to edit the first question again.
I found that the duplicate closure interface won't let me select a Staging Ground question as the target.
What should I do?

For reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78988767
https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78988310

rel with a workaround: Question flagged and closed as a duplicate of its own Staging Ground post

Closing as dupe of itself is a bug, using q/ instead of staging-ground/ to close as a dupe which is described in the answer is a workaround, which might be exploiting a bug, or it's just working as intended, nobody knows. But the Q/A contains a workaround for the problem posted here. @M-- ;-)

"decided to repost the question in the Staging Ground again" - you can't do that. They decided to post again, and the site decided the copy should go to the staging ground. That adds a strong aspect of implementation failure to the story, in my book.

You can still use Staging Ground questions as duplicate targets if both questions are from the same user.
However, this is not possible using the /staging-ground URL. Instead, copy the post ID (after the /staging-ground/ and paste that in the duplicate modal:

Alternatively, you could use links like https://stackoverflow.com/q/<id> or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/<id>.

Too complicated. This needs to be easier; there should be an option directly within Staging Ground. The real problem here is that our Beneficent Overlords are having a complete failure of the imagination as to the degree of whack-a-mole we are forced to engage in on a daily basis.

"there should be an option directly within Staging Ground" for what exactly?

The duplicate closure system should handle this automatically.
